# Excel Error:1004 - Trying to write cell formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'll try to make this as short as possible.
I need to rewrite the formulas of a number of cells depending on what worksheet they're located in.

```
Dim sFrmla As String
Dim rSomerange As Range

Let sFrmla = "=OFFSET(INDIRECT(INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & "E" & Chr(34) & "&ROW()));0;"

Let rSomerange.Formula = sFrmla & wsSheet.Name & "_ZERO_SCALE)"
Let rSomerange.Formula = sFrmla & wsSheet.Name & "_FULL_SCALE)"
Let rSomerange.Formula = sFrmla & wsSheet.Name & "_PRCSUNIT)"
```

This crashes at the second line (Zero_scale) and gives me a runtime error 1004. I have already made sure that the range itself exists and is writable.

Funny part is that the same code but without the formula string works just fine.

```
Let rSomerange.Formula = wsSheet.Name & "_ZERO_SCALE)"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. there is no need to use `Let` keyword. It's odd in this case.
2. no matter what is the default separator for your regional
   settings (comma `,` or semicolon `;`), you should always use comma
   `,` with `Range.Formula`. If you'd like to use your regional
   separator (semicolon `;` in your case), use `Range.FormulaLocal`
   instead.

So, you should use:

```
sFrmla = "=OFFSET(INDIRECT(INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & "E" & Chr(34) & "&ROW())),0,"
rSomerange.Formula = sFrmla & wsSheet.Name & "_ZERO_SCALE)"
```

or

```
sFrmla = "=OFFSET(INDIRECT(INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & "E" & Chr(34) & "&ROW()));0;"
rSomerange.FormulaLocal = sFrmla & wsSheet.Name & "_ZERO_SCALE)"
```

or shorter version:

```
sFrmla = "=OFFSET(INDIRECT(INDIRECT(""E""&ROW())),0,"
```

Comment: Yeah that was the problem, thanks a lot buddy. :)
Just wish the errors weren't so damn cryptic though.